# How to write this Crystal Report formula as an SSRS Expression?

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, activereports, grapecity

I want to convert this Crystal formula into SSRS Expression:

Formula:

```
 numberVar iDay := ToNumber(Right(Cstr({@PrntStartDate}), 2)) + 9;
    select iDay
     case 1 : {wk_TORIO0430_b.AcquisitionAmnt1}
     case 2 : {wk_TORIO0430_b.AcquisitionAmnt2}
     case 3 : {wk_TORIO0430_b.AcquisitionAmnt3}
     case 4 : {wk_TORIO0430_b.AcquisitionAmnt4}
     case 5 : {wk_TORIO0430_b.AcquisitionAmnt5}
```

How can I write this in SSRS Expression?

Comment: What part of the conversion are you stuck on? May we see your work?

Comment: @halfer Thanks for Correcting my Mistake Sir, I am new to StackOver flow next time  I will keep in mind about guideline

Comment: @halfer Sir , I need to Convert this Crystal Report formula there are 43 formula like Above and I need to Convert them, So please I am requesting you if you know Something about it ,Please Help me.

Comment: Do you already have a SSRS parameter to replace `{@PrntStartDate}`? Do you know conceptually what this expression is doing? The SSRS equivalent of `select case` is `switch`. The equivalent of `ToNumber` is `CInt` I think

Comment: How can iDay ever be 1 - 5 if you add 9 to (apparently) a day of the month?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what the first line of this is doing as I don't use Crystal Reports myself, but at Nick said in the comments, the `select case` can be rewritten using a `switch` statement. A possible solution to fix the first line would be to add a similar statement to a calculated field and using that field in the switch.  You'll have to figure out the logic being used for the `numberVar iDay` line so you can put it in as it should be.

```
=SWITCH(Fields!iDay.Value = 1, wk_TORIO0430_b.AcquisitionAmnt1,
        Fields!iDay.Value = 2, wk_TORIO0430_b.AcquisitionAmnt2,
        Fields!iDay.Value = 3, wk_TORIO0430_b.AcquisitionAmnt3,
        Fields!iDay.Value = 4, wk_TORIO0430_b.AcquisitionAmnt4,
        Fields!iDay.Value = 5, wk_TORIO0430_b.AcquisitionAmnt5)
```

Comment: I think iDay is a temp variable, not a field. The `Fields!iDay.Value` should be replaced with `VAL(Right(Cstr(Parameters!PrntStartDate.value), 2)) + 9`.

Comment: I couldn't decipher that first line, so I just answered the logic for the switch.  He's going to have to figure out how to get `iDay` set to 1-5.  If he responds and clarifies that line, I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @HannoverFist Thanks for giving me solution Sir, But It won't worked ,I tried to replace  numberVar iDay := ToNumber(Right(Cstr({@PrntStartDate}), 2)) + 9; over  VAL(Right(Cstr(Parameters!PrntStartDate.value), 2)) + 9 this  But I not able to understand how to Make all This Expression please help me.

Comment: @Steve-o169  As  I written above code iDay is Variable not a Parameter  or Field it's Variable and I am not able to Make this SSRS Expression , Please Help me.